# Windows 8 music player ("xbox music"): how to save currently playing song

Tags: windows-8

I downloaded a song in IE10 from my Google Play account, and was clicking a bit too fast so instead of choosing "save as" I just went straight to "open file". Well, the new music player in Windows 8 hides any menus that the old media players had, so I am not sure how to save the song currently loaded into it. What I had to do to get the file was open up the Temporary Internet Files folder and snag it from there, but shouldn't there be a better option within the music player itself...? Anyone aware of how to get more menu options in "Xbox Music" to do this?

Comment: You can't save a streaing song.  JUst download the song again.

Comment: It wasn't streaming...like I said the file was downloaded but only to Temporary Internet Files because I didn't click Save As in IE. I just want to know if there is a file-like menu in Windows 8

Comment: Also, the reason I can't download the song again is because Google Play limits you to two downloads per song.

Comment: The Music application looks at your My Music library folder.  You could have just searched for the file name, artist, ect.

Comment: That's true, I suppose that could be a workaround. Thanks